# When I hover on element it's shaking. How fix?

Tags: html, css

I have a heading text and a button below it. When I hover on button, the text into the heading and the button is shaking. I fixed it with the css property backface-visibility and then the text into the elements was blurred. How to solve this problem without the blurry effect ?
e.g.  https://codepen.io/yozhikk/pen/odJVeY

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #777777;
  padding: 30px;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.8), rgba(40, 180, 131, 0.8)), url(../img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 75vh, 100% 0%)
}

.logo-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.logo {
  height: 35px;
}

.heading-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}

.heading-primary-main {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 35px;
  display: block;
  animation: moveInLeft 1.5s ease-out
}

.heading-primary-sub {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 17.4px;
  display: block;
  animation: moveInRight 1.5s ease-out
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  transition: all .2s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.btn {}

.btn-white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777777;
}

@keyframes moveInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100px)
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(10px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0)
  }
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px)
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-10px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0)
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo-box">
    <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="" class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="heading-primary">
      <span class="heading-primary-main">outdoors</span>
      <span class="heading-primary-sub">is where live happens</span>
    </h1>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Discover our tours</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines:

```
.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}
```

They move the button up on hover / active for no apparent reason, which I assume is the shaking you are talking about. So just not doing that should fix it.

Comment: I think that is an intentional effect he created for :hover, but I also don't see any other flickering..

Answer (score 0):

Give the same property you added to the hover state to the initial state but make it invisible. If you give the hover state (border : 2px solid and pink;) add it in the initial state but you can make the color transparent( border: 3px solid transparent;) so it won't show before hovering on it